# Set Quantmod chartSeries line color from green to another color

Tags: r, charts, quantmod

Using version.string R version 2.11.0 (2010-04-22)
quantmod   "0.3-17"
Windows XP

When using the `chartSeries` function in `quantmod` with `type="line"` the line color that is displayed  on the chart is green. I would like to change the color from green to another color.

It looks like  i can change the `chartTheme`, but the theme does not explicitly have a variable to change the color of the plot display for lines.

I can change the line display color  when using the  `plot()` function -  So is it possible to change the display of line plots to a different color using `chartSeries()` in `quantmod`?

Comment: another way to do this is to `setDefaults(chartSeries, up.col="gold")`. That way you don't have to keep calling `chartSeries( ..., theme = chartTheme(up.col='gold') )` with each call to `chartSeries`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than cluttering its argument list with options controlling all aspects of chart appearance, `chartSeries()` has a single `theme` argument. `theme` accepts a `chart.theme` object that controls the colors of most parts of the plot, bundling all of those color choices into a single object.

The function `chartTheme()` creates `chart.theme` objects of the appropriate form.  Among the options listed in  `?chartTheme`, `up.col` seems to control the color you are asking about:

```
require(quantmod)
getSymbols("YHOO")
chartSeries(YHOO, type="line",
            theme = chartTheme("black", up.col='gold'))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! - that did the job - I thought the up.col dn.col were only for the matchstick and candle stick colors- once you know the answer its easy - Thanks!! Tuffgoat